# How to add checkbox to uicollectionview in swift

Tags: swift, checkbox, uicollectionviewcell

some time ago someone already asked this question and a few answers were given but i didn't really understand any of them. So i was wondering if anyone could please write an easy to understand tutorial on how to do the things shown on the image below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4mDm.jpg

I would be so greatful if anyone can share exactly how to this because it looks really cool and i would love to use something similar in my application

Comment: create custom cell and add button inside it. perform the conditions on it

Comment: i create custom cell and added button inside it, but when i select one of them the other cells is selected automatically, what i need it user can select multiple food when taps on checkbox in the same cell

Comment: you have to work with the button's tag. button.tag = indexPath.row and after checking the button's tag you can do it. @ahmedcool

Comment: I have added an answer may you get help from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/pronebird/CollectionViewCheckbox) is the example project available with checkbox cell. (objective - c)

*MyCell.m*

```
// A setter method for checked property
- (void)setChecked:(BOOL)checked {
    // Save property value
    _checked = checked;

    // Update checkbox image
    if(checked) {
        self.checkBoxImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Checked"];
    } else {
        self.checkBoxImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Unchecked"];
    }
}
```

*Your Collection View Cell*

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Deselect cell first
    [collectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    // Get selected cell
    MYCell* cell = (MYCell*) [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Check if set contains selected cell indexPath
    if([self.checkedIndexPaths member:indexPath])
    {
        // User tapped on checked cell
        // Remove selected indexPath from set
        [self.checkedIndexPaths removeObject:indexPath];

        // Uncheck checkbox on cell
        cell.checked = NO;
    }
    else // User tapped on unchecked cell
    {
        // Add selected indexPath to set
        [self.checkedIndexPaths addObject:indexPath];

        // Check checkbox on cell
        cell.checked = YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: ok this is work, but i dont need user taps on cell, i need user taps on checkbox himself